# VBA Address Match ruins data validation of referenced cells

Tags: excel, vba

I use a simple VBA macro to add to a cell that I find by using address and match seen below. The code works as intended, however when I added data validation to the referenced cells, the data validation is erased when the macro runs. Can someone explain why this is happening or a work around?

```
Sub Add1()


Sheets("Emp_Data").Cells(Application.Match(Sheets("CLAIM_ASSIGNMENT").Range("F32"), Sheets("Emp_data").Range("B1:B200"), 0), Application.Match(Sheets("CLAIM_ASSIGNMENT").Range("E32"), Sheets("Emp_data").Range("A1:AU1"), 0)).Value = Sheets("Emp_Data").Cells(Application.Match(Sheets("CLAIM_ASSIGNMENT").Range("F32"), Sheets("Emp_data").Range("B1:B200"), 0), Application.Match(Sheets("CLAIM_ASSIGNMENT").Range("E32"), Sheets("Emp_data").Range("A1:AU1"), 0)).Value + 1
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Referencing and updating values in cells won't erase validation.

Are you sure the process that updates the values in the references cells isn't removing the validation? If data is being pasted it from another workbook, it will also paste in the validation unless you choose to paste only values.